# Layout Master/Flow not work android

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi i have my custom Master/Flow layout but for tablet not work.

My ListActivity Layout is:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_default" />


<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/item_list"
    android:name="it.package.ItemListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    tools:context="it.package.ItemListActivity"
    tools:layout="@layout/list_custom_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

My Detail Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_default" />


<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/item_detail_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="it.package.ItemDetailActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />


</LinearLayout>
```

And for tablet the TwoPane Layout is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    tools:context="it.package.ItemListActivity">

    <!--
    This layout is a two-pane layout for the Items
    master/detail flow.

    -->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_default" />

    <fragment android:id="@+id/item_list"
        android:name="it.unifi.package.ItemListFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/list_custom_content" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/item_detail_container" android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

For smartphone all works, but in Tablet i have white page..

Comment: What is your res folder structure?

Comment: iin Res/Layout i have the first two layout. And in the Res/layout-sw600dp i have TwoPane layout

Comment: I think it has to do something with your `toolbar_actionbar`. What are the `layout_width` and `layout_weight` of that?

Comment: yes i try just now if i erase the toolbar all work..the parameters that you want are: android:layout_width="match_parent" but i'm not configure layout_weight

Comment: did that solve your problem?

Comment: no for now not..i see only the ToolBar but other is white..If i remove the ToolBar i see all but not the Toolbar of course

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73078/discussion-between-antonio-balduzzi-and-hoomi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    tools:context="it.package.ItemListActivity">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/item_list"
        android:name="it.package.ItemListFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/list_custom_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_detail_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/background_color"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: hi, i check and the first element of list is under ToolBar..how can fixed?

Comment: I am not behind my laptop. Will look into it when get back